# What will happen if I made a mistaken configuration of DNS Reverse Lookup in IIS?

Tags: iis-7

I have configured a correct DNS in my wndows 2008 server, all my websites works well.

Now I hope to configure DNS Reverse Lookup, so I read http://www.windowsreference.com/dns/how-to-create-dns-reverse-lookup-zone-in-windows-server-2003/.
but I do not completely understand  ßthe article, what will happen if I make a mistake in my Reverse DNS Lookup configuration ?
Will all my websites become unaccessable ?

Comment: How can check if  DNS Reverse Lookup is correct?

Comment: If my server's IP is 50.30.14.56, at the Network ID for “Reverse Lookup Zone Name”, I should fill in 50.30.14 , is it right?

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/209352/networkID.PNG

Comment: That depends on how the reverse resolution of the IP address was delegated to you by the owner of the 50.30.14.0/24 block, which we can't know. I'd suggest you ask whoever assigned you that IP address. See [RFC 2317](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2317) for an explanation of the most common setup. (Well, the most common is probably where whoever owns the /24 does the DNS for you and you just tell them the hostnames. But the common where the end user does it is RFC2317 style if you have less than a /24.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will add the option to translate your IP to a name. If you configure your reverse DNS in the wrong way, your A records will still work unless you start to mess with that zone. As on the how to test it, you can use dig to look for pointer records.

Comment: Thanks! Could you tell me the details about how to use dig to look for pointer records? I'm a beginner.

Comment: dig -x x.x.x.x where x.x.x.x is your ip

Comment: What problem will cause if I don't setup DNS Reverse? It seems that everything is OK, I can receive and send email, and can access website, why need I setup DNS Reverse ?

Comment: Reverse DNS is important for one particular application.
 Many e-mail servers on the Internet are configured to reject incoming e-mails from any IP address which does not have reverse DNS.
 So if you run your own e-mail server, reverse DNS must exist for the IP address that outgoing e-mail is sent from.

Comment: When I dig -x 50.31.14.26, I get the result   http://dl.dropbox.com/u/209352/bb.PNG  ,does it mean my vps hosting provider have setup Reverse DNS correct? Thanks!

Comment: It resolves to their IP so it is set up. I suggest you contact your VPS provider.

Comment: Will my emails (my domain is www.aa.com) be OK when the reverse DNS entry is resolved to vps provider chi18.softsyshosting.com ?

Comment: That depends on the spam application, but normally there should be no problem. You will always be able to send emails, but they might end up in spam. If this answer is useful, you can vote it up or accept it :)